# pthread and array, how to rewrite same position?

Tags: arrays, c, pthreads, c99, ansi-c

I am having problems with an `array[MAX]` of `p_thread`.  When my array is full, I return on the first position and make a `pthread_join(array[0], NULL)`. Later, when I try to have a `pthread_create(array[0] ... .. )`, all fail.

This is the function that fail, is part of server that comunicate with clients via socket.
The strangest thing is that if i decide to increment the index of wlist[], the execution go fine (Undefined space is write)....

What am I doing wrong?

```
typedef struct worker_t {
    pthread_t tid;
    int channel;
    int libero;
} worker_t;

worker_t wlist[THREADMAX];

static int dispatcher(){
    int test = -1;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0 ;
    int client_channel;
    while(pending_sig == 0){
        if((client_channel = acceptConnection(channel_fd)) == -1){
            if (errno == EINTR){
                continue;
                }else{
                perror(ACCEPTCON);
                return -1;
            }
        }
        while(wlist[i].tid != 0 ){
            i++;
            count ++;
            if ( count >= THREADMAX){
                if(i >= THREADMAX){
                    i = 0;
                }
                pthread_join((wlist[i].tid),NULL);
                break;
            }

            wlist[i].channel = client_channel;


            if ( pthread_create(&(wlist[i].tid), NULL, worker_start,
                  &(wlist[i].channel)) != 0) {
                perror(THRCREATE);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you put a `return 0;` at the end of a `while` loop?

Comment: Why do you `break` after the `pthread_join()`ing?

Comment: the return 0 is for a control in the main, the break...because when i have joined the oldest wlist[i].tid p_thread (the first of the array i=0, i++) i want to create a new thread passing wlist[i].tid (after the join....but i recive some pointer error)

Comment: RESOLVED: just the p_thread_join too slow...and the client disconnect....i've set int libero (of struct worker_T) to 1 (by the thread) before the thread_exit